# Cannot display latex in Sympy

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter, sympy, jupyter-lab

`enter code here`I am a beginner in jupyter and am trying to do symbolic computations using sympy.
after running the following code

%matplotlib inline

import sympy as s

s.init_printing()

from IPython.display import display_latex

theta=s.symbols('theta')
print(theta)

instead of getting the symbol for theta the output is "theta"
I can get latex display in markdown cell so I don't thins that this is a mathjax issue

I am using jupyterlab 3.0.14

I know this is a duplicate but implementing fixes other discussions didn't resolve my issue

Comment: There's nothing to fix. `print(theta)` should do as you describe.  To see the theta symbol, follow along with the first two cells from [here](https://github.com/josephcslater/Introduction_to_Python/blob/master/SymPy_Examples.ipynb), and then in your third cell put `theta=symbols('theta')` and run that and then in the fourth cell just put `theta` and run that cell. Or put `display(theta)` and run that cell. `simplify(theta)` in a cell and run also works.

Comment: Think of `print()` as stemming from Python's basic abilities. It's not going to be part of support for showing fancy rendering in Jupyter. In other words, by default, `print()` is going work in Jupyter just like it would if you were running in the Python interpreter in a very basic command line / terminal situation.

Comment: `expand(theta)` will also work to replace `display(theta)` as the fourth cell in the first example I provided. You can test this all out right in your browser at https://www.sympy.org/en/shell.html now using JupyterLite in embedded form (see https://twitter.com/jtpio/status/1523660682708668416 for more about the tech behind the [SymPy Online Shell](https://www.sympy.org/en/shell.html)). I took the `expand()` from the examples on the right side at the the [SymPy Online Shell](https://www.sympy.org/en/shell.html).

Comment: working on offline jupyterlab ,display(theta) takes forever to compute. Its working fine online. other operations, offline works just fine as well

Comment: What are you meaning by "offline jupyterlab"? The [JupyterLab Desktop App](https://blog.jupyter.org/jupyterlab-desktop-app-now-available-b8b661b17e9a) when computer isn't connected to the internet? Honestly, I didn't think they had achieved offline JupyterLab quite yet. I thought there were some things from CDNs it still needed, but maybe you got it set up online and then went offline? So I'm not quite following.